# I want to compress an image in view before saving, but the file size stays the same

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, python-imaging-library

I have a functional update view that I am trying to compress uploaded images before saving them. However, when I try to compress the image, nothing happens and instead just saves the image with the exact same size.

I think I might be saving it wrong, but I am unsure of how to save it correctly. Please let me know. Thank you!

````py
import io
from PIL import Image


def get_compressed_image(file):
    image = Image.open(file)

    with io.BytesIO() as output:
        image.save(output, format=image.format, quality=20, optimize=True)
        contents = output.getvalue()
        return contents


def updated_form_view(request)
    ...
    
    if initial_form.is_valid():
        initial_form.clean()
        updated_form = initial_form.save(commit=False)
        updated_form.username = request.user.username

        # compressing image here
        updated_form.form_image.file.image = get_compressed_image(updated_form.form_image)


        updated_form.save()```
````

Answer (score 0):

we must reduce the resolution of picture, like this:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("logo.jpg")
amount = 1.5 # higher amount: more reduction. lower: less reduction
width, height = img.size

new_size = int(width // amount), int(height // amount)
compressed = img.resize(new_size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
compressed.save("compressed.jpg")
```

less resolution + no exif info = less size

and take note ur code worked but ur code dont ***change the resolution of picture*** but it pixelize image like this:
[just click it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tbLB.png)

Comment: how would you use this inside of django or in my get_compressed_image function?

Comment: add line 8 in my code above line 9 in ur code and remove args of line 10 except output and format in ur code. `compressed = image.resize((width, heigh), Image.ANTIALIAS)` in new line `compressed.save(output, format=image.format)`